# PVC size need for multiple 14/2 landscape wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, landscaping

What size PVC do I need if I wanted a conduit to run 3 or 4 14/2 landscape wire for an under concrete PVC concrete install?

And does schedule 40 or 80 matter for an under concrete install?

Comment: your title and main body say different things, is it 14/2 or 12/3

Comment: try this tool https://www.southwire.com/calculator-conduit

Comment: sorry, i mean 14/2

Comment: Please do not update your question by asking a new one. Instead, please edit the changes into your previous question: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/274211/landscape-wire-in-pex-piping-for-under-concrete-installation

Comment: @Ruskes does that calculator work for landscape wire, which is basically like big lamp cord?